# updating a column by comparing multiple columns in pyspark data frame

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have a `data frame` in `pyspark` like below.

```
+-----+---+---+----+
|tests|val|asd|cnty|
+-----+---+---+----+
|test1|  Y|  1|null|
|test2|  N|  2|  UK|
| null|  Y|  1|  UK|
|test1|  N|  2|null|
|test1|  N|  3|null|
|test3|  N|  4| AUS|
|test4|  Y|  5|null|
+-----+---+---+----+
```

I want to update the value when the any given `tests` or `cnty` has val `Y` then all val's of that particular `tests` or `cnty` should be updated to `Y`. if not then what ever values they have.

I have done like below

```
from pyspark.sql import Window
import pyspark.sql.functions as f


df1 = df.select('tests', f.max('val').over(Window.partitionBy('tests')).alias('val'), 'asd', 'cnty')

+-----+---+---+----+
|tests|val|asd|cnty|
+-----+---+---+----+
|test1|  Y|  1|null|
|test1|  Y|  2|null|
|test1|  Y|  3|null|
|test2|  N|  2|  UK|
|test3|  N|  4| AUS|
|test4|  Y|  5|null|
| null|  Y|  1|  UK|
+-----+---+---+----+
```

The above doesn't give me the desired result. As you can see for `test2` I have `cnty` as `UK` and `val` is `N` and I have another record where `cnty` is `UK` and the `val` for that record is `Y`  Then according to my requirement the `val` for both these records should be `Y`. But this is not the case in the `result`.

Comment: just run the same command, but partitioned by `cnty`: 
df2 = df1.select('tests', f.max('val').over(Window.partitionBy('cnty')).alias('val'), 'asd', 'cnty')

Comment: @jxc Looks like it works but I am unable to understand the behaviour why doesn’t it work with ‘tests’ but work with ‘cnty’

Comment: it works when you use cnty because uk are grouped as one and max of that group is Y. but when you used tests they became two groups and max of one is Y and another is N. See my answer below for detailed explanation and solution how you can achieve your desired result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You checked only for tests column but you forgot to check for cnty column. For that you would*need another windowSpec for cnty column and combine both windowSpecs using `when` inbuilt function to get your desired result

```
from pyspark.sql import window as w
windowSpec1 = w.Window.partitionBy('tests').orderBy('asd')
windowSpec2 = w.Window.partitionBy('cnty').orderBy('asd')

from pyspark.sql import functions as f
df = df.select(f.col('tests'), f.when(f.max('val').over(windowSpec1)== 'Y', 'Y').otherwise(f.when(f.max('val').over(windowSpec2)== 'Y', 'Y').otherwise(f.col('val'))).alias('val'), f.col('asd'), f.col('cnty'))
df.show(truncate=False)
```

which should give you

```
+-----+---+---+----+
|tests|val|asd|cnty|
+-----+---+---+----+
|test4|Y  |5  |null|
|test3|N  |4  |AUS |
|test1|Y  |1  |null|
|test1|Y  |2  |null|
|test1|Y  |3  |null|
|test2|Y  |2  |UK  |
|null |Y  |1  |UK  |
+-----+---+---+----+
```

I hope that explains why you are not getting the desired result.

**Update**

Above solution requires both `window` functions to run at the same time which might lead you to some issues with memory. You can run one `window` function each for checking `tests` and `cnty` columns separately as

```
from pyspark.sql import window as w
windowSpec1 = w.Window.partitionBy('tests').orderBy('asd')
windowSpec2 = w.Window.partitionBy('cnty').orderBy('asd')

from pyspark.sql import functions as f
df = df.withColumn('val', f.when(f.max('val').over(windowSpec1)== 'Y', 'Y').otherwise(f.col('val')))\
    .withColumn('val', f.when(f.max('val').over(windowSpec2)== 'Y', 'Y').otherwise(f.col('val')))
```

this will generate the same result.

Comment: Maharajan Your solution seems to work on small sized data but on large size data it is causing issues like `spill to disk`. is there a way we can avoid using `window partitions` and achieve the result I want

Comment: @user9367133, using window function is the best solution that I know of for the problem that you have. Now `spill to disk` might be because you are using both window function at once. You can modify the solution to use one window function in each checking condition. If you don't understand what I am saying , tell me and I shall help you with that

Comment: Maharajan Actually I am new to using `windows` functions. Could you please let me know how to modify the solution to use one window function in each checking condition

Comment: @user9367133, I have updated my answer. :) hope it helps you to resolve your issue.

Comment: @RameshMaharjan Can we use the same `windows` functionality to update many columns in a single statement. I mean  to say here you are updating `val` column, say If I want to update another column as well in the sngle statement say `registered`  based on the `tests` and `cnty` columns as in the question.

Comment: you can use the same window functionality but not in the same expression. An expression can generate only one column at a time when used with .withColumn @Question_bank

Answer (score 1):

You can try following approach. Left join dataframe to the same dataframe filtered with '`Y`' values on a right: if found apply `Y`, otherwise pick up existing value.

```
df.alias('a').join(
    df.filter(col('val')='Y').alias('b'),
    on=(col('a.tests') == col('b.tests')) | (col('a.cnty') == col('b.cnty')),
    how='left'
  )
  .withColumn('final_val',when(col('b.val').isNull(), col('a.val')).otherwise(col('b.val')))
  .select('a.tests','a.asd','a.cnty','final_val')
```

The only problem, there might be duplicates, but it's better to test with the data and do deduplication at the end if needed.

Comment: In your answer `.withColumn('final_val',when(col('b.val').isNull(),` I believe that this shouldn't be there because you are filtering the `df` `df.filter(col('val')='Y').alias('b')` so `val` in `b` will not have `null` values at all. I think this would be `.withColumn('final_val',when(col("b.val == 'Y'"), col('b.val')).otherwise(col('a.val')))` the correct statement

Comment: It's `left` join that produce empty values for whole b.* part. Solution is correct.

Comment: @Rumoku Can we use the same `join` to update many columns in a single statement. I mean to say here you are updating `val` column, say If I want to update another column as well in the single statement say `registered` based on the `tests` and `cnty` columns as in the question

Comment: @Question_bank of course, you can chain as many `withColumn` statement as you want, one after another within different conditions: `...withColumn('final_val'..).withColumn('final_reg',..).with...`